# Undefined Function?

Tags: python

I am not sure why I am getting an error that game is not defined:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# global variables
wins = 0
losses = 0
draws = 0
games = 0

# Welcome and get name of human player
print 'Welcome to Rock Paper Scissors!!'
human = raw_input('What is your name?')
print 'Hello ',human

# start game
game()

def game():
    humanSelect = raw_input('Enter selection: R - Rock, P - Paper, S - Scissors, Q - Quit:  ')
    while humanSelect not in ['R', 'P', 'S', 'Q']:
        print humanSelect, 'is not a valid selection'
        humanSelect = raw_input('Enter a valid option please')

    return humanSelect

main()
```

Comment: Move `game()` to after you're done with `def game`

Answer (score 4):

Because, at the time the statement `game()` is executed you have not yet reached the statement `def game():` and game is, therefore, undefined.

If you move `game()` to after `def game()` you will then get a similar error on `main()` which is harder to fix as you don't appear to be defining a function called `main` anywhere in the code.

Answer (score 3):

You have to define the function `game` before you can call it.

```
def game():
    ...

game()
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I spent some time tinkering with this today and now have the following:

```
import random
import string

# global variables
global wins
wins = 0
global losses
losses = 0
global draws
draws = 0
global games
games = 0
# Welcome and get name of human player
print 'Welcome to Rock Paper Scissors!!'
human = raw_input('What is your name? ')
print 'Hello ',human

def readyToPlay():
    ready = raw_input('Ready to Play? <Y> or <N> ')
    ready = string.upper(ready)

    if ready == 'Y':
        game()
    else:
        if games == 0:
            print 'Thanks for playing'
            exit
        else:
            gameResults(games, wins, losses, draws) 

    return

def game():

    global games
    games += 1
    human = humanChoice()
    computer = computerChoice()
    playResults(human, computer)
    readyToPlay()


def humanChoice():
    humanSelect = raw_input('Enter selection: R - Rock, P - Paper, S - Scissors:  ')
    while humanSelect not in ['R', 'P', 'S']:
        print humanSelect, 'is not a valid selection'
        humanSelect = raw_input('Enter a valid option please')
    return humanSelect

def computerChoice():
    computerInt = random.randint(1, 3)
    if computerInt == '1':
        computerSelect = 'R'
    elif computerInt == '2':
        computerSelect = 'P'
    else:
        computerSelect = 'S'

    return computerSelect

def playResults(human, computer):

    global draws
    global wins
    global losses

    if human == computer:

        print 'Draw'
        draws += 1

    elif human == 'R' and computer == 'P':

        print 'My Paper wrapped your Rock, you lose.'
        losses += 1

    elif human == 'R' and computer == 'S':

        print 'Your Rock smashed my Scissors, you win!'
        wins += 1

    elif human == 'P' and computer == 'S':

        print 'My Scissors cut your paper, you lose.'
        losses += 1

    elif human == 'P' and computer == 'R':

        print 'Your Paper covers my Rock, you win!'
        wins += 1

    elif human == 'S' and computer == 'R':

        print 'My Rock smashes your Scissors, you lose.'
        losses += 1

    elif human == 'S' and computer == 'P':

        print 'Your Scissors cut my Paper, you win!'
        wins += 1

def gameResults(games, wins, losses, draws):
    print 'Total games played', games
    print 'Wins:  ', wins, ' Losses:  ',losses, ' Draws:  ', draws
    exit

readyToPlay()
```

I am going to work on the forcing the humanSelect variable to upper case in the same manner that I did with ready, ready = string.upper(ready).  I ran into indentation errors earlier today, but will iron that out later tonight.

I do have a question.  Is it possible to use a variable between the () of a raw_input function similar to this:

```
if game == 0:
    greeting = 'Would you like to play Rock, Paper, Scissors?'
else:
    greeting = 'Play again?'

ready = raw_input(greeting)
```